# LayOut Inflater in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I have created a subclass of `View` as an inner class in my `Activity`. I just want to inflate an xml into the class which extends `View`. Can anyone provide some code/syntax of both class and xml?

```
public class DrawAct extends Activity {

       DrawView drawView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        drawView = new DrawView(this, null);
         setContentView(drawView);


    }
    public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
        Path path;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;
        private ArrayList<Path> graphics = new 
        public DrawView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context,attrs);
            //I want to load the contents of an xml in this class
    //
  }

}
```

xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.drawing"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="200dip"

     android:layout_gravity="right"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: For me it's not clear enough. Can you share part of your code?

Comment: @Cristian: I have pasted the code. Can you please have a look now?

Comment: @Cristian: i don't know how to add UI components inside the class which extending View

Comment: What's the reason you need your own "extended" version of `View`?

Comment: @Asahi:I want to use onDraw()....etc in my application

Answer (score 1):

Just keep in mind that once you have inflated something, it will be just `View` object. Not sure what you want to do, but can do something like:

```
public class drawiact extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        drawView = new DrawView(this, null);
        setContentView(drawView);
    }
    public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
        Path path;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;
        private ArrayList graphics = new 
        public DrawView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context,attrs);
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
            // then do whatever you want with the 'view' object
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Cristian: I tried this code. But it doesn't showing any widgets in XML file. My need is to give action to the ImageView and Button widgets which is in the loaded XML.

Comment: @Cristian: Is it possible to load xml into View and make actions for the objects.

Comment: Place your views (objects, TextView, buttons, etc.) in your_layout.xml and them access them by calling `view.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view)`

Comment: @Asahi:I tried this code. But it also doesn't showing any widgets in XML file.Should I make any modification for xml...??

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.drawing"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    
     android:layout_gravity="right"></Button>
   

</LinearLayout>

Comment: The button is defined as `wrap_content` and it does not have any content. Could be a reason you do not see it. Another point: if you have overridden any methods make sure to call `super` where needed.

Comment: By the way... why do you have two `setContentView` invokations?